# ReactJS can not disable a dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, bootstrap-4

Using ReactJS I create a form dynamically using custom JSON data.

```
render() {      
    return (
        <div>       
            <ShowForm src={this.state.data} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

With `componentDidUpdate` I would like to disable all `submit` buttons. While the label of the buttons is changed successfully, I constantly fail to disable the button.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    var submitButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button[type=submit]');
    submitButtons.forEach(btn => {
        btn.innerText = 'PREVIEW';
        btn.disabled = true;
    });
}
```

The chrome inspector returns the following HTML code for the buttons. Also, the form objects are using Bootstrap for the CSS styling.

```
<button lang="en" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" type="submit" name="data[Draft]" ref="button">PREVIEW</button>
```

What prevents JS to apply the `disable` action?

Comment: Because you're trying to use native JS to manipulate the DOM inside a React environment.

Comment: Usually when you have to use `querySelectorAll` in react it means you did something wrong

Comment: @Konrad I don't think so, because I didn't use ```querySelectorAll``` as a preference but rather as a necessity. React just couldn't manage this kind of situations.

Comment: @Andy There are situations that direct manipulation of the DOM is a necessity. If you have to suggest another solution, you are welcome. I suppose there must be a way for this problem.

Comment: How do you create the buttons?

Comment: @Konrad As I already mentioned, html buttons are created dynamically using a JSON data ie ```{component : 'button', label : 'click me', width: '100'}```

Comment: Why are you trying to update those buttons every time the component updates @Maverick. You surely just need to set them once _at some point_.

Comment: @Andy These buttons are not part of any React Component. They are HTML buttons that a React Component generates ie ShowForm dynamically at runtime. I don't need to set them at any time, because they are used as a preview without any other functionality. The buttons also have some extra Bootstrap CSS styling ie an animated circle that I don't want to be triggered and confuse the user. As you can see in my answer below React dev team has made provisions in situations like this and with web-components can keep your data in sync with shadow DOM.

Comment: @Maverick. Nice. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web components is the preferred solutions

https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html

Alternatively, you can manipulate the JSON data before they are rendered from react-dom.

Another solution I found is simply set `pointer-events: none;` style.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    var submitButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button[type=submit]');
    submitButtons.forEach(btn => {
        btn.setAttribute('style', 'pointer-events: none;');
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution :) *Alternative, I can manipulate the JSON data before they rendered from react-dom.* -  Isn't that how you normally do things in react?